# Remove triples with no context from a Redland graph

Tags: rdf, redland

I am using the Redland librdf library and would like to remove all triples with no associated context node from a graph. I tried passing `NULL` as the context node pointer to `librdf_model_context_remove_statements`, but that results in `rdf_model.c:1358: (librdf_model_context_remove_statements) assertion failed: object pointer of type librdf_node is NULL.`

Is there any API call I have missed to do this, or would I have to iterate every triple in the graph and examine the context?

If Dave is reading, why is passing NULL not allowed?

Comment: *or would I have to iterate every triple in the graph and examine the context?* -- does Redland provide something like `librdf_statement_get_context`? *Is there any API call I have missed to do this?* According to [similar logic](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-model.html#librdf-model-find-statements-in-context), passing NULL should be equivalent to `librdf_model_remove_statements` which is not implemented. I guess you should use `librdf_model_find_statements_in_context` and then, iteratively, `librdf_model_remove_statement`.